# How do I map Unicode Values on an android custom keyboard to KeyEvents?

Tags: android, android-softkeyboard

I am attempting to build a custom keyboard that is built into an application (not an external keyboard) so the key flow is a little different.

```
<Key android:codes="241" android:keyLabel="ñ" />
<Key android:codes="180" android:keyLabel="´" />
<Key android:codes="231" android:keyLabel="ç" />
<Key android:codes="161" android:keyLabel="¡" />
<Key android:codes="191" android:keyLabel="¿" />
```

Within it, I need to intercept the key event generated by the on-screen keyboard and forward it to the current EditText with:

```
EditText.dispatchKeyEvent(evt);
```

If we pass the KeyEvent as-is to EditText, it will not display the current value, I need to map it to constants in the https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent (KeyEvent class).

I was able to successfully do this for all the characters on a standard English Keyboard.  I can't however find the mappings for the Spanish characters.

How can I map the Spanish characters to KeyEvents to be sent to the EditText?

Comment: We've tried sending KeyEvents with key codes from 0 to 13,500 with metaState values of 0 and 1 so far. No joy. The test is still running. Looks like its going to take a few hours to get to 0XFFFF;

Comment: Part of the problem we were having was getting an InputConnection from the context always returned null. Kevin decided to try creating the IC "manually" and by golly it worked. 
Something like:

InputConnection ic = mCurrentEditText.onCreateInputConnection(editorInfo);